# Disable Saving/Exporting Results of TSQL Query in SSMS?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, permissions

I really don't want to go in to too much detail as to WHY I want to do this. Just know that it would be ideal for my use case.

Is there a way to disable a specific database role from using the `Copy`, `Copy with Headers`, `Save Results As...`, `Print...` functionality in the results window in `SSMS`?

[image: SQL]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no way to handle this from the database/instance, unless you just deny them access to the database at all.

SSMS is a client-side tool, and the things that it can do with the data you've already let it consume are outside of server-side controls. Even if you could take those menu items away, there is always the PrintScreen button.

Comment: Right, that makes sense. Thank you.

Comment: I disagree - don't grant those people SELECT if they can't be trusted with the data.

Comment: @George.Palacios But it seems the OP wants them to be able to *view* the data, just not print / save.

Comment: @AaronBertrand yeah I get that - I'm being a little flippant but my point is that even if you restrict this particular method, they'll find some other way.

Comment: @George yep, and that's why my answers says, no, there is no way. I added some clarity.